# Is there a better way of calling LINQ Any + NOT All?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to check if a sequence has any items satisfying some condition but at the same time NOT all items satisfying the same condition.

For example, for a sequence of 10 items I want to have TRUE if the sequence has at least one that satisfy the condition but not all:

- 10 items satisfying, 0 items not, result is FALSE
- 0 items satisfying, 10 items not, result is FALSE
- 1 item satisfying, 9 items not, result is TRUE
- 9 items satisfying, 1 item not, result is TRUE

I know I could to this:

```
mySequence.Any (item => item.SomeStatus == SomeConst) && !mySequence.All (item => item.SomeStatus == SomeConst)
```

But this is not optimal.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You could probably use `.Aggregate` with a custom type that holds properties for the needed information - just an input ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair That'd work, but I don't think you can abort an aggregate as soon as you've found both options so you'd complete the iteration even if you didn't need to.

Comment: @Rup absolutely true. I wasn't aware that the OP is after a short-curcuit variant ...

Comment: If your sequence is a collection that has a `Count` or `Length` property, it might be cheaper to get `.Count(item => item.SomeStatus == SomeConst)`. If the value is greater than 0 and less than the collection size, return true. If the sequence is an `IEnumerable<T>`, your implementation is probably more optimal due to short circuiting.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll like this.

```
var anyButNotAll = mySequence
    .Select(item => item.SomeStatus == SomeConst)
    .Distinct()
    .Take(2)
    .Count() == 2;
```

The `Take(2)` stops it iterating over any more elements than it has to.

Comment: Note that you'd almost certainly want to throw this in a method, such as `SomeButNotAll`, just for the sake of clarity, because this code, as it is, doesn't do a great job of self-documenting.

Comment: this will iterate over the whole collection at least once to do the `.Select` and then the `.Distinct`...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair No, it won't.

Comment: That is VERY nice. I did the same thing but without the `Take(2)` and deleted it when I realised my blunder. +1

Comment: @Rawling ah thanks, thought that `.Distinct` needs some overhead. my initial comment should have been more like a question though ;)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair It uses a little overhead in building up a `HashSet`, but since it builds it up as it goes it can still exhibit delayed execution :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Both of the methods you listed only evaluate as many items from the source sequence as they need to in order to compute the next item in the sequence; they don't need to evaluate the whole sequence to compute the next item.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair It needs to remember all items previously yielded, meaning it's memory footprint is O(m) (where m is the number of items yielded so far) unlike methods such as `Select` or `Where` that have a memory footprint of O(1).

Comment: @Servy for `.Select` this was absolutely clear to me, but I haven't investigated the source for `.Distinct` yet ... so, for clarification: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4ab583c7d8e84d6d

Comment: would doing a `GroupBy(x => x.SomeStatus == SomeConst).Take(2).Count() == 2` would be more overhead than `Select` and `Distinct`?

Comment: @DLeh It probably wouldn't shortcut the way this will, as it'd need to complete the iteration to complete the groups.

Comment: @Rup that's what I was thinking

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/4j3hcq) is a link to an ideone page where you can see for yourself that this only evaluates as many as it needs.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Heh, I'd just done exactly that: http://ideone.com/LifIR2 because I didn't know Distinct would behave like that. But it's also obvious from the source Andreas linked to.

Comment: @Rup Why would `Distinct` need to iterate the entire collection to yield, say, the first item?  Even ignoring the source code, just thinking logically about it is generally sufficient.

Comment: @Servy thinking logically could imply some naive thinking too (which I did ...) ... so, stick to the source - that's the only truth :)

Comment: The .Take(2) seems unnecessary to me since the .Distinct() can only return two values for a boolean type.

Comment: @Maarten `Enumerable.Count()` requires a full evaluation, whereas `Enumerable.Take()` shortcuts the execution.

Comment: @Maarten The `Take` doesn't change the result, but it does prevent the query from asking `Distinct` for a third item, which would require it to completely evaluate the rest of the sequence to determine that there isn't one.

Comment: Genius answer! I love it. :-)

Answer (score 6):

If your concern is iterating through all of the elements in a large collection, you're okay - `Any` and `All` will short-circuit as soon as possible.

The statement

```
mySequence.Any (item => item.SomeStatus == SomeConst)
```

will return true as soon as one element that meets the condition is found, and

```
!mySequence.All (item => item.SomeStatus == SomeConst)
```

will return true as soon as one element does not.

Since both conditions are mutually exclusive, one of the statements is guaranteed to return after the first element, and the other is guaranteed to return as soon as the first element is found.

---

As pointed out by others, this solution requires *starting* to iterate through the collection twice.  If obtaining the collection is expensive (such as in database access) or iterating over the collection does not produce the same result every time, this is not a suitable solution.

Comment: But what if the source sequence doesn't return the same items if iterated multiple times, or does expensive computation to compute it's items?

Comment: So it's as good as it can possibly be, except for all of the extremely common cases where it isn't...  Acknowledging that your answer is wrong in your answer doesn't make it not wrong.

Comment: @Servy No need to be snarky.  LINQ is frequently used for static, in-memory collections where the above problems do not apply.  Limited applicability of a solution does not make it wrong.

Comment: And it's frequently used for other types of sequences where it *doesn't* apply.  So saying that a particular solution is "as good as it can get" when there are frequent situations in which is performs *dramatically* worse than alternatives, it is not in fact "as good as it can get".  If you want a solution that's "as good as you can get, at least in certain circumstances" then just have the implementation "return true;" it's by *far* the best implementation in all of the circumstances where there are items that do and don't meet the condition.

Comment: `Limited applicability of a solution does not make it wrong.` That would be true if the OP were just looking for any solution to the problem, and wasn't concerned about performance.  But when you say, "it's as good as it can get" when it's not as good as it can get, then *it is in fact wrong*.  It would be correct to say that it is a solution, it's *incorrect* when you claimed that it was an optimal solution.

Comment: The question is asking, "is there a better way".  Your answer is "no, what you have is fine".  That answer is incorrect, there are better ways, ways that are more efficient and don't have the rather noticeable drawbacks of this answer in both performance and correctness.

Answer (score 3):

That is likely a fairly optimal solution if the source is a database.  This extension method might be better depending on your source (I think, I just threw it together -- likely many many errors, consider it more pseudo code).  The benefit here is it only enumerates once and does a short-circuit as soon as it has read enough to determine the outcome:

```
static bool SomeButNotAll<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                   Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
   using(var iter=source.GetEnumerator())
   {
     if (iter.MoveNext())
     {
       bool initialValue=predicate(iter.Current);
       while (iter.MoveNext())
         if (predicate(iter.Current)!=initialValue)
           return true;
     }
   }     
   return false; /* All */
}
```

Comment: You'll need to accept a `Func` not an `Expression`, since you plan on invoking it, and since you only plan to iterate `source` and do nothing else, you should accept an `IEnumerable` and not an `IQueryable`.

Comment: Dispose of your enumerators.

Answer (score 3):

You could define your own extension method. This version is more verbose, but still readable, and it only enumerates the `IEnumerable` once:

```
bool AnyButNotAll<ItemT>(this IEnumerable<ItemT> sequence, Func<ItemT, bool> predicate)
{
    bool seenTrue = false;
    bool seenFalse = false;

    foreach (ItemT item in sequence)
    {
        bool predResult = predicate(item);
        if (predResult)
            seenTrue = true;
        if (!predResult)
            seenFalse = true;

        if (seenTrue && seenFalse)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Much shorter, but enumerates the `IEnumerable` twice:

```
bool AnyButNotAll<ItemT>(this IEnumerable<ItemT> sequence, Func<ItemT, bool> predicate)
{
    return sequence.Any(predicate) && !sequence.All(predicate);
}
```

Comment: You can exchange `if (!predResult)` for `else`

Comment: @roman You're right; I'm not sure why that didn't occur to me. I guess I was thinking of the two `if` statements as being more or less independent.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
var result = mySequence.Select(item => item.SomeStatus == SomeConst)
                      .Distinct().Count() > 1 ? false : true;
```

Basically I select `true` or `false` for each value, get distinct to only get one of each, then count those.

Comment: Note this prevents short circuiting in the event that the first item is true and the second false.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your predicate in a variable so that you don't have to repeat the predicate twice:

```
Func<MyItemType, bool> myPredicate = item => item.SomeStatus == SomeConst;
if (mySequence.Any(myPredicate) && !mySequence.All(myPredicate))
    ...
```

Comment: This change is purely stylistic, and has no effect on how it performs at all, which is what the question is asking about.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't aware that the asker wasn't interested in purely stylistic suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to define this as a method, you could take then approach Linq takes in defining both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` extension methods. This allows for the optimal approach to be taken automatically:

```
public static bool SomeButNotAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
  if(source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  if(predicate == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
  return source.
    Select(predicate)
    .Distinct()
    .Take(2)
    .Count() == 2;
}
public static bool SomeButNotAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
  if(source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  if(predicate == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
  using(var en = source.GetEnumerator())
    if(en.MoveNext())
    {
      bool first = predicate(en.Current);
      while(en.MoveNext())
        if(predicate(en.Current) != first)
          return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

If you're using EntityFramework (or another provider that provides a `CountAsync` you can also provide an asynchronous version easily:

```
public static async Task<bool> SomeButNotAllAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, CancellationToken cancel)
{
  if(source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  if(predicate == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
  cancel.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  return await source.
    Select(predicate)
    .Distinct()
    .Take(2)
    .CountAsync(cancel)
    .ConfigureAwait(false) == 2;
}
public static Task<bool> SomeButNotAllAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
  return source.SomeButNotAllAsync(predicate, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Aggregate method to do both things at once. I would suggest to use an anonymous type for the TAccumulate, containing both counters. After the aggregation you can read both values from the resulting anonymous type.

(I can't type an example, I'm on my phone)

See the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: `Aggregate` doesn't short circuit - this will require iterating through the entire collection.